# program crash in std::sort() sometimes, can't reproduce

Tags: c++, vector, stl, crash

## Description:

My program crash sometimes in `std::sort()`, I write a minimal program to reproduce this situation, but everything is just alright. Here is the minimal example:

```
typedef struct st {
    int it;
    char ch;
    char charr[100];
    vector<string *> *vs;
} st;

bool function(st *&s1, st *&s2) {
    static int i = 1;
    cout<<i<<" "<<&s1<<" "<<&s2<<endl;
    ++i;
    return s1->it > s2->it;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector<st *> ar;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        st *s = new st;
        s->it = urandom32();
        ar.push_back(s);
    }

    ar.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        st *s = new st;
        s->it = urandom32();
        ar.push_back(s);
    }

    sort(ar.begin(), ar.end(), function);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the GDB stack info:

> - 0  0x00007f24244d9602 in article_cmp (cand_article_1=0x7f23fd297010, **cand_article_2=0x4015**)
>     at src/recom_frame_worker.h:47
> - 1  0x00007f24244fc41b in std::__unguarded_partition<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
>     cand_article*, bool (*)(cand_article*, cand_article*)> (__first=,
>     __last=, __pivot=@0x7f230412b350: 0x7f23fd297010,
>     __comp=0x7f24244d95e1 )
>     at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_algo.h:2266
> - 2  0x00007f24244f829c in std::__unguarded_partition_pivot<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, bool
>     (*)(cand_article*, cand_article*)> (__first=, __last=,
>     __comp=0x7f24244d95e1 )
>     at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_algo.h:2296
> - 3  0x00007f24244f1d88 in std::__introsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, long,
>     bool (*)(cand_article*, cand_article*)> (__first=, __last=,
>     __depth_limit=18,
>     __comp=0x7f24244d95e1 )
>     at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_algo.h:2337
> - 4  0x00007f24244ed6e5 in std::sort<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, bool
>     (*)(cand_article*, cand_article*)> (
>     __first=, __last=, __comp=0x7f24244d95e1 )
>     at /usr/include/c++/4.8.3/bits/stl_algo.h:5489

`article_cmp` is called in `sort(article_result->begin(), article_result->end(), article_cmp);` and article_result is a `vector<cand_article*> *`. `cand_article` is a struct.
Here is the definition of `article_cmp`:

```
bool article_cmp(cand_article* cand_article_1, cand_article* cand_article_2) {
    return cand_article_1 -> display_time >= cand_article_2 -> display_time;
}
```

Here is a piece of code where the crash happens:

```
 article_result->clear();
 for(vec_iter = _channel_data -> begin(); vec_iter != _channel_data -> end(); vec_iter++) {
     cand_article* cand = to_cand_group(*vec_iter);
     if(cand == NULL) continue;
     // refresh open loadmore
     if(m_request.req_type == 1) {
         if(cand -> display_time > m_request.start){
             article_result->push_back(cand);
         }
     }else if(m_request.req_type == 2){
         if(cand -> display_time < m_request.end){
             article_result->push_back(cand);
         }
     }else{
         article_result->push_back(cand);
     }
 }

 sort(article_result->begin(), article_result->end(), article_cmp);
```

## Question:

I don't know how to handle this kind of `coredump`, cause `0x4015` is a kernel space address? Any suggestions on how to fix this kind of bug? sorry, I can't reproduce this situation with a minimal program. And this happened in a `single thread`, so you don't need to think about `multi-thread` situation.

Comment: 0x4015 is not a kernel address, but it might be a damaged pointer, or the result of dereferencing a member in a NULL pointer. However, your `article_cmp()` function doesn't seem to have anything to do with the other code you posted, so what's going on ? Do you have any code people can compile and run that also crashes ?

Comment: @nos I paste a piece of code, the project is too large.

Comment: `typedef struct st` and `new st` tell me that you're not familiar with C++. Your error suggests a memory corruption, which is indeed not easy to reproduce in a simple program. But the style of C++ you're inadvertently using does lead easily to memory corruptions.

Comment: @MSalters can you refer me to a sample, so I can know why?

Comment: @CharlesLiuChina: Not easy to explain in a comment. Three main things: Memory corruption is best avoided by using objects instead of pointers to objects, by using smart pointers if you still have to use objects, and by using [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for these tips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is "if `std::sort` crashes, you have an invalid comparison function".  Your comparison function is:

```
bool article_cmp(cand_article* lhs, cand_article* rhs) {
    return lhs -> display_time >= rhs -> display_time;
}
```

This is not a strict weak ordering.  In particular, if the display times are equal it returns `true`, which means that if you swap the arguments it will *still* return `true` ... and that is not allowed.  You need:

```
bool article_cmp(cand_article* lhs, cand_article* rhs) {
    return lhs -> display_time > rhs -> display_time;
}
```

The reason your simplified example works (congratulations for at least *trying* to simplify), is that you simplified the comparison function so it is valid.  If the return statement was `return s1->it >= s2->it;`, and you used a smaller range of values, it too would probably crash.

Incidentally, a much more natural C++ declaration of your example structure would look like:

```
struct st {                       // No need for that typedef in C++
    int it;
    char ch;
    std::string charr;            // ... or *possibly* std::array<char,100>.
    std::vector<std::string> vs;  // Strings and vectors best held by value
};
```

Also note that I have actually used the `std::` prefix.

Comment: Thanks, we have modified the code, and watch for one day. If the crash doesn't happen, I'll accept your answer. Thank you so much. And `cpp reference` also metioned `strict weak ordering`. ^_^

Comment: It was crashing for me because i was returning an integer, not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your minimal program is making memory leaks. Because it just removes all the items from the list but did not release the memory used by them. In the case your items are big enough, your program might get crashed after eating up all the memory. That's why your minimal program is still okay, because the items there are very small.
2. I would change your program to:

   typedef struct st {
       int it;
       char ch;
       char charr[100];
       vector *vs;
   } st;

   bool function(st *&s1, st *&s2) {
       static int i = 1;
       cout<it > s2->it;
   }

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       vector ar;
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
           st *s = new st;
           s->it = urandom32();
           ar.push_back(s);
       }

   ## release all the memory used my ar's items first

   for (vector::iterator it = ar.begin(); it != ar.end(); ++it) 
       delete *it;

   ar.clear();

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
       st *s = new st;
       s->it = urandom32();
       ar.push_back(s);
   }

   sort(ar.begin(), ar.end(), function);

   return 0;
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks, I know that indeed. ^_^ And thanks again for pointing out.

Comment: if after changing this, your program is still crashing, I can think of another issue. That is if your program using any other lib which is complied stl in release mode and the other part of your program using stl in debug mode. This might crash your app as well. The way to check is try compiling your app in both release and debug mode then run them 2 and see. Hope this will help you solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for this tip.